# Get dates between date of ID and date of plus or minus days

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE tblDates
(
    ID int,
    Dates DATE
);

SELECT * FROM tblDates

INSERT INTO tblDates VALUES(1,'2019-12-01');
INSERT INTO tblDates VALUES(2,'2019-12-05');
INSERT INTO tblDates VALUES(3,'2019-12-02');
INSERT INTO tblDates VALUES(4,'2019-12-09');
INSERT INTO tblDates VALUES(5,'2019-12-11');
```

Here I am looking for dates between `date` of `ID = 4` and plus or minus of days 1,2,....n days.

Try 1: I tried using UNION ALL.

```
SELECT Dates FROM tblDates WHERE ID = 4 
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(day,1,Dates) FROM tblDates WHERE ID = 4;
```

This approach is not good for when I am looking for 50 or more number of days difference.

Try 2:

```
SELECT Dates FROM tblDates WHERE ID = 4 AND Dates between Dates AND DATEADD(day,1,Dates);
```

Got single date.

Try 3:

Created function: function for get dates

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_GetDates(@MinDate DATE,@MaxDate DATE)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1)
        Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate)
FROM    sys.all_objects a
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b;
```

Query:

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM udf_GetDates(t.Dates,DATEADD(day,1,t.Dates)) f        
INNER JOIN tblDates t ON f.[Date] = t.[Dates]
WHERE t.ID = 4
```

Got an error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 The multi-part identifier
>   "t.Dates" could not be bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 The
>   multi-part identifier "t.Dates" could not be bound.

Expected Output:

Given: ID = 4 and day=+1

```
Dates
----------- 
2019-12-09
2019-12-10
```

Given: ID = 4 and day=+10

```
Dates
----------- 
2019-12-09
2019-12-10
2019-12-11
2019-12-12
2019-12-13
2019-12-14
2019-12-15
2019-12-16
2019-12-17
2019-12-18
```

Given: ID = 4 and day=-5

```
Dates
----------  
2019-12-05
2019-12-06
2019-12-07
2019-12-08
2019-12-09
```

Comment: use a `recursive query` or `join` with a `tally` table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e5d6f/2)

**Function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_GetDates (@StartDate DATE, @Range INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT  
        DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, @StartDate) myDate
    FROM    
        (SELECT    
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.object_id) AS Nbr
         FROM      
             sys.columns c) nbrs
    WHERE   
        nbr - 1 <= @Range
```

Query usage #1:

```
SELECT f.myDate 
FROM udf_GetDates((SELECT dates FROM tblDates WHERE ID = 4), 2) f
```

Query usage #2:

```
SELECT t.*, P.*
FROM tblDates t 
OUTER APPLY udf_GetDates(t.Dates, 5) p
WHERE t.ID = 4
```

Updated answer:

Next Dates

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_GetDates (@StartDate DATE, @Range INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT  
        DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, @StartDate) myDate
    FROM    
        (SELECT    
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.object_id) AS Nbr
         FROM      
             sys.columns c) nbrs
    WHERE   
        nbr - 1 <= @Range
```

Previous Dates

```
CREATE FUNCTION [udf_GetDates_Minuus] (@StartDate DATE, @Range INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT  
        DATEADD(DAY, -(nbr - 1), @StartDate) myDate
    FROM    
        (SELECT    
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.object_id) AS Nbr
         FROM      
             sys.columns c) nbrs
    WHERE   
        nbr - 1 <= @Range
```

Next and previous dates in single function

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_GetDatesNextandPrevious(@StartDate DATE, @Range INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT  
        DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, @StartDate) myDate
    FROM    
        (SELECT    
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.object_id) AS Nbr
         FROM      
             sys.columns c) nbrs
    WHERE   
        nbr - 1 <= @Range

    UNION

    SELECT  
        DATEADD(DAY, -(nbr - 1), @StartDate) myDate
    FROM    
        (SELECT    
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.object_id) AS Nbr
         FROM      
             sys.columns c) nbrs
    WHERE   
        nbr - 1 <= @Range
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/46008/2)**

Comment: @MAK There is no error from my side, even you could check it in the fiddle demo. Execute my funtion and try it properly

Comment: This is okay for plus days, but minus days? For example `Given: ID = 4 and day= - 5`

Comment: @MAK I have updated my answer. It will post you plus or minus 5 days from the given date.

Comment: @VigneshKummarA, Almost done! Can you please alter the function so that I can call it separately for plus and minus dates?

Comment: If I just want to get plus dates then it should display current date(i.e ID =4) and next date. If want to get minus dates then it should display current date(i.e ID =4) and previous date. For example plus 1: `2019-12-09` and `2019-12-10` and for minus 1: `2019-12-08` and `2019-12-09`.

Comment: And for calling function I'm using your "Qurey Usage 2" which perfectly fine for me.

Comment: @MAK You can get the results now

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in sql server

```
DECLARE @selecteddate DATE 
DECLARE @day INT = 10 
DECLARE @id INT = 4; 
DECLARE @count INT = 0; 
DECLARE @table1 TABLE 
  ( 
     date_ DATETIME 
  ) 

SELECT @selecteddate = dates 
FROM   tbldates 
WHERE  id = @id; 

IF( @count <= @day ) 
  BEGIN 
        if(@day > 1)
        begin 
            set @day = @day - 1
        end
      WHILE @count <= @day 
        BEGIN 

            INSERT INTO @table1 
            VALUES      (Dateadd(day, @count, @selecteddate)) 

            SET @count = @count + 1 
        END 
  END 
ELSE 
  BEGIN 
      WHILE @count > @day 
        BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO @table1 
            VALUES      (Dateadd(day, @count, @selecteddate)) 

            SET @count = @count - 1 
        END 
  END 

SELECT * 
FROM   @table1 
ORDER  BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create function using another format

```
create FUNCTION udf_GetDates(@MinDate DATE,@MaxDate DATE)
RETURNS @_result table (dt date)
AS
begin
    insert into @_result
    SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1)
            Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate)
    FROM    sys.all_objects a
            CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b;
    return
end
```

and select the result like this

```
declare @_date date=(select Dates from tblDates where ID=4)
select *
from udf_GetDates(@_date,DATEADD(day,1,@_date))
```

and I got the result what you wanted

```
dt
2019-12-09
2019-12-10
```

Answer (score 0):

This SQL will return the correct dates between two ranges. Just adapt it to suite your needs.

```
    DECLARE @From               DATETIME,    
            @To                 DATETIME

    SELECT  @From           =   '2019-11-13',
            @To             =   '2019-11-19'

    ;WITH   Numbers         AS
(
    SELECT  0               AS  Number
UNION ALL
    SELECT  Number + 1      AS  Number
    FROM    Numbers
    WHERE   Number          <   DATEDIFF(d, @From, @To)
)
    SELECT  DATEADD(d, 
            Number, @From)  AS Date
    FROM    Numbers
```

-- Results

```
2019-11-13 00:00:00.000
2019-11-14 00:00:00.000
2019-11-15 00:00:00.000
2019-11-16 00:00:00.000
2019-11-17 00:00:00.000
2019-11-18 00:00:00.000
2019-11-19 00:00:00.000
```